# Why does clearInterval(...) not seem to be doing its job here?

Tags: javascript

**Repro steps:**

- Go to http://playclassicsnake.com/Play
- Click "Fast" (or "Slow" or even "Medium") on "Set Speed" under "Controls"
- Hit left arrow key and wait until snake hits left wall and "Game Over!"
- Look at JavaScript console
- See something like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

- Refresh the page
- Hit left arrow key and wait until snake hits left wall and "Game Over!"
- Don't see same error in the console as before

**My investigation:**

The reason for the error is that the function `move` in the first case is being called after "Game Over!" and in the second case isn't. The second case is the correct behavior. In both cases a function `endGame` that starts out like

```
this.endGame = function ( msg )
{
    this.inProgress = false;
    clearInterval(this.mover);
```

is being called, but for some reason the interval is failing to clear in the first case. It makes no sense because the only difference between what happens in the first case and second case is that in the second case the speed is set with

```
SG.setSpeed($('#speed-form input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
```

on page load to start game, and in the first case it is set with that and then updated with

```
$('#speed-form input[type="radio"]').click(function ( )
{
    SG.setSpeed($(this).val());
});
```

when you click one of the radio buttons. I've tested with

```
this.endGame = function ( msg )
{
    console.log(this.mover); // TEST
    this.inProgress = false;
    clearInterval(this.mover);
```

that in both cases `this.mover` is defined. For reasons I don't understand and that may have to do with my problem, in the first case the the ID of the interval is always a high number like `68`, `74`, etc., while in the second case it is always `2`!

I have no idea what's going on here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Full code [here](https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Scripts/game.js).

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! Don't forget to make a [mcve].

Comment: Try modifying your function `setSpeed` to clear the interval `this.mover` before setting the new one, if it exists.

Comment: the problem is that `this.mover` gets an integer and not the function because of the `if` statement you did there

Comment: @JCOC611 Thanks. That fixed it (on my local version; I haven't updated the site yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when you were calling `clearInterval(this.mover);`, you were only clearing the *last* interval set to `this.mover`, and **all** intervals before it were being left untouched. The solution I proposed (which seems to have worked) was to clear the previous interval every time a new one is set. This takes care of that issue because there is at most *one* interval at any given moment.